# WooCommerce Separate Attribute & Variations

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have a WooCommerce store that has multiple "size groups" i.e. Adult Sizes, Youth Sizes, Ladies Sizes, etc..

Each product can have multiple size groups, so the user can select "Adult Large" or "Ladies Small". The problem is when I go to setup the variation, it combines the groups. So I will have to set a price for "Adult Small & Ladies Large" rather than just one.

Is it possible to separate the variables into their own variations?

See the screenshots for more info:

Group sizes are separate on the attributes tab
[image: Group sizes separated into variables]

But when viewing the variations it combines them so the user cannot select just one size....
[image: Group sizes combined on variations]

Comment: Instead of doing that, **logically** you should have an attribute like "kind" (or something else) with Ladies, Mens, Youth. //\\  And another attribute with the sizes Small, medium, large … This is the only way to get what you want with product variations.

Comment: @LoicTheAztec that sounds like a possible solution. I will run that by the client and see if that will work for them. I appreciate the response!